# page create in Modal Dialog box and return parameter in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, spdialog

i need to create enterprise wiki page in Modal Dialog box ,when user enter name of the wiki page after click on save button.then it should return parameter.return parameter use for another process like redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

open dialog box to create wiki page
     function openDialogAndReceiveData() {
         var options = {
             url: "MycreateWikiPage.aspx",
             dialogReturnValueCallback: onClose
         };
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
     }

```
 function onClose(result, returnValue) {
     if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
     { 
        //this is a value from dialog box
        alert(returnValue);
     }
 }
```

in dialog box (MycreateWikiPage.aspx), onclick on Save button:

```
 function closePopupAndPassData() {
     //your code to create wiki page
     ...
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, "my info for another page");
 }
```

[full code](http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-pass-or-return-value-from-a-SharePoint-2013-Modal-Popup-Dialog-to-the-Base-Page)

see also [commonModalDialogClose options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409682%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and showModalDialog options _https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409609(v=office.14).aspx